# Не получается сконнектить Telegram с MS Bot Framework

Tags: c#, бот, telegram, bot-framework

Пробую поднять бота с помощью недавно вышедшего Bot Framework и через Bot Connector соединить его с Телеграмом.

Сам бот создан, залит на Azure и прекрасно отвечает в Bot Framework Emulator. В Телеграме тоже бот уже создан, токен получен.

Но картина вот такая:

[image: Но картина вот такая]

В Channels я прописал телеграмовский токен. Однако в столбце "Published" недоступен переключатель. Я подумал, что здесь поможет добавление галки "Publish in Bot Directory" в настройках бота на портале. В итоге статус добавления бота "Pending approval", и вроде как надо подождать, но меня смущает, что сама Bot Directory по сути ещё не функционирует ("coming soon"), и возможно переключатель недоступен по какой-то другой причине. Да и жду уже полдня.

В общем, хотелось бы услышать кого-нибудь, кто уже подсуетился с созданием бота на Bot Framework, чтобы развеять мои сомнения.

Comment: Чтобы развеять ваши сомнения. :)
Я тоже никак не могу дождаться Published, похоже появление в общем каталоге пока закрыто для всех (там их всего 6 официальных). Однако боту в Телеграме это не мешает.

Comment: Да, мне тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36472270/bot-framework-teleram-channel-not-published уже тоже ответили, что бот и без этого должен функционировать.Осталось только понять механизм законнекчивания бота с телеграмом. Сейчас в Телеграме на любое сообщение прилетает ответ: Operation returned an invalid status code 'MethodNotAllowed'. Навыки программирования и чтения по-английски у меня довольно низкие, поэтому пока разбираюсь

Comment: Разобрался. Неправильно заполнил endpoint на портале

Comment: Расскажите пожалуйста, как ПРАВИЛЬНО заполнить endpoint?

Comment: @DenisKolesnikov https://site.azurewebsites.net/api/messages - вместо "site" вписать то, имя, которое задали вы

Comment: @Eugene, было бы отлично если бы Вы оформили развёрнутый ответ на свой вопрос, раз уж решение нашлось.

Comment: @Anatol пардон. написал

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос поднимался в то время, когда бот-платформа только появилась и Bot Directory на тот момент не отображала созданных на этой платформе ботов и соответствующие переключатели не были доступны, что никак не мешало работе самих ботов.

Как там сейчас ситуация с бот-платформой обстоит, я не знаю, ибо забросил, поскольку после очередного её обновления возникла необходимость переписывать вообще весь код.

А к дальнейшему моему вопросу про endpoint добавить нечего. Насколько я помню, я так просто не дописал "/api/messages".